# Can we modify the serializer fields based on view and user type?

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a `User` serializer with the below fields, I am trying to add only some fields for List view but want to return different set of fields for Detail View, these are the fields:-

```py
super_user_list_fields = ( 'id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'birth_date', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', )
```

```py
super_user_detail_fields = ( 'id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'bio', 'url', 'company', 'location', 'phone_number', 'birth_date', 'notes', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions', 'last_login', 'date_joined', )
```

```
normal_user_list_fields = (.......,)
```

```
normal_user_detail_fields = (........,)
```

These is my serilaizer:-

```py
class UserSerializer(serilaizers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = super_user_list_fields
```

I have two views first one is extensions of `ListCreateAPIView`, and second is `RetrieveUpdateDestroy`.

Now I also want to change some of these fields based on the type of `user` objects such as a different set of fields for superUsers, non-superusers, etc. ....

I am thinking if there could be some method like this:-

```py
class serializer(...):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = get_the_required_fields()
        ..........
        ..........
        .........
    def get_the_required_fields(self, ....):
    user = self.request.user
    if user.is_superuser and (viewtype is ListCreateAPIView):
        return super_user_list_fields
    if user.is_superuser and (viewtype is RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        return super_user_detail_fields
     .........
     ........
     .......
```

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

Answer (score 0):

```
class DynamicFieldsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)


class Serializer(DynamicFieldsAllTransactionSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ModelName
        fields = "__all__"

Serializer(QuerySet,many=True,fields=('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'birth_date', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups',))
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem.